# MotionEvent.ACTION_UP is not called

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener, ontouchlistener, motionevent

i have a problem with an `OnSwipeImageListener` (implements `OnTouchListener`). I use the `OnSwipeImageListener` in two activities.
On the one activitiy on the `ImageView` is the `OnTouchListener` and an `OnClickListener` and on the other activity on the `ImageView` is only the `OnTouchListener`.
If i change return v.`onTouchEvent(event)` to `true` under the `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` then the `OnClickListener` on the first activity doesn't work and in this way the Swipe of `ImageView` on the second activity doesn't work. I debugged some times and see that `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP` is never called.

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

    switch(event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        dX = event.getX();
        dY = event.getY();
        return v.onTouchEvent(event);
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        uX = event.getX();
        uY = event.getY();

        float deltaX = dX - uX;
        float deltaY = dY - uY;

        // horizontal
        if(Math.abs(deltaX) > MIN_DISTANCE) {

            //Left to right
            if(deltaX < 0) {
                this.onLeftToRight();
                return v.onTouchEvent(event);
            } else if (deltaX > 0) {
                this.onRightToLeft();
                return v.onTouchEvent(event);
            }
            else {
                //Swipe too short
                return v.onTouchEvent(event);
            }
        }

        // vertical
        if (Math.abs(deltaY) > MIN_DISTANCE) {

            if(deltaY < 0) {
                this.onTopToBottom();
                return v.onTouchEvent(event);
            } else if (deltaY > 0) {
                this.onBottomToTop();
                return v.onTouchEvent(event);
            }
            else {
                //Swipe too short
                return v.onTouchEvent(event);
            }
        }
    }
    return v.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the ACTION_UP, you should hijack the ACTION_DOWN.

Instead of returning "`v.onTouchEvent(event)`", return "`true`" when you are just handling the ACTION_DOWN.

Comment: Yes, you should do your work in "ACTION_UP" section (and considering if current position is out of your view's boundary) instead of in "OnClick". That is equal.